# create hw_diamonds.csv in outcome directory

Tags: python

Create a CSV file named hw_diamonds.csv in the outcome directory. The file contains 7 column names carat, cut, color, clarity, depth, table, and price in the first row and the values from the corresponding columns of df in the following rows. The delimiter is a slash (/) for columns and a new line (\n) for rows. For example, the first 3 rows in the file must look as below. Do not use Pandas.

Should return this:
carat/cut/color/clarity/depth/table/price
0.23/Ideal/E/SI2/61.5/55.0/326
0.21/Premium/E/SI1/59.8/61.0/326

```
with open("outcome/hw_diamonds.csv", "w") as fw:
    header = "carat/cut/color/clarity/depth/table/price\n"
    fw.write(header)
    print(header, end="")

    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        carat = row.carat
        cut = row.cut
        color = row.color
        clarity = row.clarity
        depth = row.depth
        table = row.table
        price = row.price
    
        line = "{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}/{}\n".format(carat, cut, color, clarity, depth, table, price)
        fw.write(line)
        print(line, end="")
```

Comment: Can't we use: `df.to_csv('outcome/hw_diamonds.csv', sep='/')` ?

Comment: I assume `df` is a `Pandas` dataframe only?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @hacker315 *"Do not use Pandas"* I'm assuming this is a homework question